# SettingWithCopyWarning when using the assignment operator "="

Tags: python, pandas

I read some answers and documentation about this, and I'm still a little confused about why the warning is occurring and finding another way to accomplish the same thing. I get the desired results, but would prefer to not have a warning in my logs.

This does not generate the warning:

`df[(df['column1'].isin(sequence) | df['column2'].isin(sequence))]`

This, which helps me reduce the dataframe, does generate the warning:

`df = df[(df['column1'].isin(sequence) | df['column2'].isin(sequence))]`

I found another way to do it, by using `concat`, but I would just prefer to use the `|` and want to learn why this is happening a little bit more in depth, if possible. The documentation implies that there is chaining or chained indexing, and talks a little about a view v.s. a copy, or something like that, and I'd like to know whether someone can help break it down to me so I understand this concept better. For now, I am using the `concat` way, because it doesn't throw a warning, but still, if any of you provide a better way, I am very open to testing it.

This worked as an alternative using `concat` and I don't get the warning:

```
df1 = df[df['column1'].isin(series)]
df2 = df[df['column2'].isin(series)]
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True, join='outer')
```

Any information that would be educational about what is happening with the `|` and `=` that generates the warning, or more efficient alternatives to accomplishing this reduction, would be helpful and appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You can actually just ignore the warning here, unless you have another reference to the data-frame, this shouldn't really affect you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `any` for the condition and add `copy` remove the warning

```
df=df[df[['column1','column2']].isin(sequence).any(1)].copy()
```

Also when you subset the data from the original dataframe, please always add the `.copy()` at the end

Comment: I will give that a try on Monday, but it looks like it makes sense. Thank you! I'll keep you updated.